# HSQLDB and Hibernate/JPA - not persisting to disk?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hsqldb

Something of an novice with HSQL and Hibernate...

```
em.getTransaction().begin();
for (Activity theActivity : activities) {
  em.persist(theActivity);
}
em.getTransaction().commit();
em.close();
```

followed by...

```
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
em.getTransaction().begin();
System.out.println("QUERY:: "
    + em.createQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + Activity.class.getName()).getSingleResult()
        .toString());
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

Prints 25000 (the number of Activity objects in activities). But when I run this test again, the number of objects in the count(*) doesn't increase (and is 0 at the beginning of the program). So the objects aren't getting durably written.

This is my hsqldb connection string:

```
name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:file:data/cmon"
```

so it's not an in-memory database as far as I know...

Does anyone have any ideas why the objects aren't getting persisted beyond a single JVM session? Happy to supply more information but there's so much state associated with Hibernate / JPA / HSQL that it's not clear exactly what is pertinent.

Comment: As another data point, the last run's INSERTs are in data/cmon.log, which is erased on startup and replaced. Maybe there's an option to force log replay at startup?

Comment: This means logging does take place. Please report the size of the .log and of any .script file in that directory. Also the version of HSQLDB you are using.

Comment: @fredt - Hibernate 1.8.0. The size of the log is about 4MB, around 37000 insert statements. cmon.script is 1.9K, and curiously ends with SET WRITE_DELAY 10 - which makes it look like my changes to the connection string aren't working.

Comment: The connection property is not supported by HSQLDB 1.8.0. Latest Hibernate 3.5.5 (2010.08.18) release supports HSQLDB 2.0.x. Get this together with the latest HSQLDB 2.0.1 snapshot jar from http://hsqldb.org/support/ and use jdbc:hsqldb:file:data/cmon;hsqldb.write_delay=true;shutdown=true

Comment: Correction: jdbc:hsqldb:file:data/cmon;hsqldb.write_delay=false;shutdown=true

Comment: @HenryR: Did  you ever get it to work? I am having the exact same problem. Logs get written, but no data.

Comment: I am having a similar problem. The persists seem to be getting through but not all of them.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> Does anyone have any ideas why the objects aren't getting persisted beyond a single JVM session?

HSQLDB doesn't write changes immediately to disk after a commit (see "[WRITE DELAY](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/guide.html#set_write_delay-section)"), HSQLDB is not Durable by default (that's from where "performances" are coming from).

Either try to set the connection property `shutdown=true` in the connection string to get the changes written when the last connection will end.

```
jdbc:hsqldb:file:data/cmon;shutdown=true
```

If it doesn't help, try to set the [WRITE DELAY](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/guide.html#set_write_delay-section) to 0 (or false). If you're using HSQLDB 1.8.x, use the SQL command:

```
SET WRITE_DELAY 0
```

If you're using HSQLDB 2.0.x, you can now also use a connection [property](http://hsqldb.sourceforge.net/doc/2.0/guide/dbproperties-chapt.html) `hsqldb.write_delay`:

```
jdbc:hsqldb:file:data/cmon;hsqldb.write_delay=false
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. So committing a transaction doesn't guarantee persistence, it seems - that's a bit counter intuitive.

Comment: @HenryR: That's exactly it, HSQLDB is not Durable **by default**. (actually, HSQLDB is not A(C)ID).

Comment: @Pascal Thivent - thanks, unfortunately that doesn't seem to have worked. My connection string is jdbc:hsqldb:file:data/cmon;hsqldb.write_delay=0;shutdown=true and there is still no durability (hbm2ddl.auto is still set to 'update')

Comment: @HenryR: I added a link to a similar question (that I couldn't find back when I wrote my answer). I believe it's the same "problem". Will test this tomorrow.

Comment: HSQLDB version 1.8.x does not support the connection property hsqldb.write_delay at all (only the SQL command is supported). Version 2.0.x supports hsqldb.write_delay=false (the SQL command is also slightly different)

Comment: @fredt: Thanks, I've clarified this in my answer.

Comment: NB hsqldb.write_delay=0 is not valid, only true or false.

Comment: Invalid Edit by anonymous user: Finally closing the EntityManagerFactory (emf.close()) before the application quits also flushes the changes to disk:

 EntityManagerFactory emf;
//set up emf
//persist some entities
emf.close();

Answer (score 9):

**The solution is :**

```
<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</property>
```

in hibernate.cfg.xml

---

*This is rest of my configuration:*

Libs:

- HsqlDb 2.0.0
- Hibernate 3.5.6

Url:

```
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:hsqldb:file:data/mydb;shutdown=true;hsqldb.write_delay=false;</property>
```

Comment: You made my day, that problem cost me some hours. +1 and thanks :)

Comment: Worked for me as I use HSQL DB 2.2.4. Thank you very very much!

Answer (score 8):

Did you set `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` to `create-drop` in your persistence.xml? This drops your tables and re-creates them on every startup.

You can set it to `update` instead, or if you want to manage the schema yourself, then set it to `validate`.

Comment: Thanks - it's set to "update", so I'm not sure if that's the problem :(

Answer (score 4):

Simply close your EntityManagerFactory with HSQL in filemode, after the commit to really persist datas...

Answer (score 4):

I was using HSQL DB version 2.2.5.
I tried above approaches i.e. setting shutdown=true and hsqldb.write_delay=false
It did not work. As suggested in some blog, I added statement

```
org.hsqldb.DatabaseManager.closeDatabases(0);
```

after transaction commit. But it did not work.

HSQL DB version 2.2.9 seems better than this. With one workaround it solves this problem.   To handle above problem take following steps :-

1) hsqldb.jar from lib of HSQL DB version 2.2.9

2) In hibernate config xml just specify URL
I am using HSQL file-based database.

```
 <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:hsqldb:file:D:\JavaProj\TmpDBLocation\myKauDB</property>
```

3) In your program at the end write statement

```
org.hsqldb.DatabaseManager.closeDatabases(0);
```

Now run the hibernate program that commits the data to DB.

Check HSQL DB by opening it in standalone mode and with URL

```
jdbc:hsqldb:file:D:\JavaProj\TmpDBLocation\myKauDB
```

You should see your changes persisted in DB.

Answer (score 1):

Closing **sessionfactory** worked for me.